# Parse @Override annotation with maven compiler plugin

Tags: java, maven-compiler-plugin

I've a maven project which doesn't parse @Override annotation, i.e. there are some @Override annotations missing in my project but when I run maven goal compile (with maven compiler plugin 3.1) it doesn't show me warning about missing @Override annotations, how can I set maven compiler plugin so that it shows warning about missing @Override annotations?
here is my plugin:

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

Comment: I've a basic idea, it could be used `<compilerArgument>` property of maven compiler plugin, but what argument do I've to pass to parse correctly missing annotations?

Comment: This looks rather like a job for a static analysis tool... But otherwise you can use `-Xlint:all` (IIRC)

Comment: Another option is to use your IDE e.g. Eclipse to detect these errors. You can even set up Eclipse to automatically add in missing @Override annotations as a save action.

Comment: I use Netbeans, and thought that I've discovered the solution: `-Xlint:overrides`, but I've already unchecked and I need only these two parameters, how can I add to parameters to Xlint? `-Xlint:unchecked overrides` doesn't work... maven returns build faulire

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
only need to add these lines to maven compiler plugin configuration:

```
    <compilerArgs>
      <arg>-Xlint:rawtypes</arg>
      <arg>-Xlint:overrides</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
```

or, more generally:

-Xlint:all

as @fge suggesten correctly in a comment to question